# Calculate percentage along with count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to show the count and percentage in a table.

The query I used is this:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate AS DATETIME
SET @BeginDate = GETDATE();

SELECT TOP 10 
    s.Title AS Title, COUNT(*) AS TotalSessions 
FROM 
    History s
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, s.DateStamp) >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, @BeginDate)
    AND CONVERT(DATE, s.DateStamp) <= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @BeginDate)  
GROUP BY 
    Title
ORDER BY 
    TotalSessions DESC
```

This returns the top 1o records and now

1. I want to show the percentage value with respect to total as the third column. Can I do this in same query?
2. I want to show the remaining count as others (if 100 records are there, first 10 rows shows top 10 records and row #11 shows sum of remaining 90 records with title "Others"). Can I do it in the same query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.  Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 s.Title as Title, count(*) as TotalSessions,
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM History s
WHERE convert(date,s.DateStamp) >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, @BeginDate)
AND  convert(date,s.DateStamp) <= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @BeginDate)  
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY TotalSessions DESC
```

Comment: Yes this will work for the first part to find percentage,